# Update position of element in Azure Maps for Android

Tags: android, azure-maps

I'm using the Azure Maps Android SDK to draw icons on the map.
The way I'm currently doing this is to add a new Datasource for each element and add a new SymbolLayer using this Datasource and a drawable for the icon.
Each time the position of an icon changes I remove this SymbolLayer and add a new one with an updated Datasource.
With every position update the icon blinks for a split second and I wish there was a smoother way.
While this works I was wondering if this really is the intended way of handling position updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve smooth animated movement of symbols by updating the DataSource itself.

Changes to the DataSource will be immediately reflected on the map via the existing layers.

```
dataSource.clear();
dataSource.add(featureCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done.  The key is the `pin.setCoordinates()` call.

Example code here...
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Animations/Simple%20Symbol%20Animation.html

And a demo here...
https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Animations/Simple%20Symbol%20Animation.html

And these examples are in JS, but I would imagine the Android SDK has the same SDK.

Comment: Unfortunaly, the Android SDK seems to differ from the JS SDK in this regard. I can't find the Shape class in the SDK und therefore can't call a setCoordinates function.